# Классы и поля в C#

Tags: c#

У меня есть первый класс игрока:

```
public class Player
{
    private string _name;
    private int _health;
    private int _coin;
    private int _coordX;
    private int _coordY;

    public Player(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
        _health = 100;
        _coin = 0;
        _coordX = 0;
        _coordY = 0;
    }
    
    // Приветствие
    public string WelcomeMessage()
    {
        return $"Hello, my name is {_name}. In my pockets {_coin} coins! and I have {_health} HP";
    }
}
```

И есть класс монетки:

```
    public class Coin
{
    Random _rnd = new Random();
    private int _value;

    public Coin()
    {
        _value = _rnd.Next(30, 100);
    }
}
```

Как можно не костыльно сделать так, чтобы у класса Player был метод TakeCoin который будет прибавлять к _coin Coin._value?

Comment: Вопрос тот же, почему "Монетка", содержит информацию про игрока? Это предмет, или некое значение, которое есть только у игрока? Если 2-е, то делайте свойство/поле в классе игрока этого класс (`private Coin Coin;`) инициализируйте его при инициализации игрока и уже дальше работайте с ним. Если же это предмет, то у вас явное нарушение...

Comment: Пример из `Unity3d`, но всё-же https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoHqS09rlTU

Comment: `Random _rnd = new Random();` Никогда не ставьте инициализацию рандома в конструктор. Ибо если вы разом проинициализируете 100 экзепляров данного класса, то все они у вас будут иметь одинаковое значение рандома. В идеале нужно использовать только один рандом вне класса, либо использовать статическое поле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В условиях минимальных правок вашей реализации, выглядеть это будет примерно вот так:

```
public class Player
{
    private string _name;
    private int _health;
    private int _coin;
    private int _coordX;
    private int _coordY;

    public Player(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
        _health = 100;
        _coin = 0;
        _coordX = 0;
        _coordY = 0;
    }

    // Приветствие
    public string WelcomeMessage()
    {
        return $"Hello, my name is {_name}. In my pockets {_coin} coins! and I have {_health} HP";
    }

    public void TakeCoin()
    {
        _coin += new Coin().Value;
    }
}

public class Coin
{
    public int Value => new Random().Next(30, 100);
}
```

С небольшими изменениями я бы предпочёл вот такой вариант. Также можно впринципе уйти от класса Coin и просто делать рандомайз числа.

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Health { get; set; }
    public int CoinsCount { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }

    public Player(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Health = 100;
        CoinsCount = 0;
        Location = new Location();
    }

    public string WelcomeMessage()
    {
        return $"Hello, my name is {Name}. In my pockets {CoinsCount} coins! and I have {Health} HP";
    }
}

public class Location
{
    public int CoordX { get; set; }
    public int CoordY { get; set; }
}

public class Coin
{
    public int Value => new Random().Next(30, 100);
}

// Некий класс, который будет описывать действия игрока, чтобы отделить действия от сущности
public class Handler
{
    public void PlayerTakesCoin(Player player)
    {
        if (player != null)
        {
            player.CoinsCount += new Coin().Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Если что-то лишнее - уберите.

```
public class Coin { //добавить в Coin
public int get_value => _value;
}

public class Player { //добавить в Player
public int TakeCoin(Coin coin = null) { // значение по-умолчанию null
   _coin += coin?.get_value ?? new Coin().get_value;
   // ?. - проверяет coin на null, ?? - если слева null - возвращает значение справа, если слева не null - только слева
   //если монетка не была получена в классе TakeCoin или монетка не была инициализирована - генерирует новую
  return _coin; //возвращает новое значение _coin (если требуется)
}
```

Тестим:

```
Player p = new Player();
WriteLine(p.TakeCoin());
Coin coin = new Coin();
WriteLine(coin.get_value);
WriteLine(p.TakeCoin(coin));
```

Если при событии получении монетки нужно обновлять какой-то GUI, а метод TakeCoin должен быть void - можно ознакомиться с делегатами:

```
// функция (якобы) обновления интерфейса
public void UpdatePanelCoinGUI(int coinsOnPanel) => WriteLine($"###{coinsOnPanel}.00###"); 
public class Player {
   private int _coin = 0;
   public delegate void UpdatePlayerCoinGUI(int coins); //объявление типа делегата
   public UpdatePlayerCoinGUI updatePlayerCoinGUI; //инициализация делегата
   //тестовая функция вызова обновления GUI для отображения coin
   public void testfuncGUI() { 
   _coin = new Random().Next(0, 100);
   updatePlayerCoinGUI?.Invoke(_coin); }
   // ? - нужен для проверки на наличие в списке вызова хотя бы одного элемента
   //, иначе будет ошибка если делегат пустой
}
Player p = new Player();
//записываем функцию UpdatePanelCoinGUI в делегат, чтобы при вызове testfuncGUI()
//и делегата внутри - вызывалась функция UpdatePanelCoinGUI
p.updatePlayerCoinGUI += UpdatePanelCoinGUI; //так можно добавить несколько функций
//тест
p.testfuncGUI();
p.testfuncGUI();
```